# Eclipse ADB is rejecting shell commands, and cannot find target of device

Tags: android, shell, adb, target, ddms

This has been addressed a few times, but I need to re-open the issue, as none of the answers either work or explain what is wrong. My phone is a rooted LGl45c, API 10, android 2.3.4.  Upon plug-in to computer, a 'ADB rejected shell command (getprop): closed' appears in logcat.  Debugging in device is on, it accepts unknown sources, USB cable is new, proper minSDK in app is 8, maxSDK is 17, DDMS version 21.1, ADT version 21.1.
  It appears that ADB cannot access the properties of my phone, and therefore upon trying to debug an app that used to work 2 weeks ago;

```
 Android Launch!
[2013-05-05 07:53:45 - SurfaceViewAnimation] adb is running normally.
[2013-05-05 07:53:45 - SurfaceViewAnimation] Performing com.example.surfaceviewanimation.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-05-05 07:53:45 - SurfaceViewAnimation] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2013-05-05 07:53:52 - SurfaceViewAnimation] WARNING: Unknown device API version!
[2013-05-05 07:53:52 - SurfaceViewAnimation] Uploading SurfaceViewAnimation.apk onto device 'A00000318350B9'
[2013-05-05 07:53:52 - SurfaceViewAnimation] Installing SurfaceViewAnimation.apk...
[2013-05-05 07:53:52 - SurfaceViewAnimation] Failed to install SurfaceViewAnimation.apk on device 'A00000318350B9!
[2013-05-05 07:53:52 - SurfaceViewAnimation] closed
[2013-05-05 07:53:52 - SurfaceViewAnimation] Failed to install SurfaceViewAnimation.apk on device 'A00000318350B9': closed
[2013-05-05 07:53:52 - SurfaceViewAnimation] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: closed
[2013-05-05 07:53:52 - SurfaceViewAnimation] Launch canceled!
```

Upon opening terminal, adb is in path:

```
pete-mint14@petemint14-Latitude-D810 ~ $ adb devices
adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached 
A00000318350B9  device
```

Unplug/replug phone in 'debug: enabled, accepts unknown sources: true' results in:

```
[2013-05-05 08:00:50 - ddms] ADB rejected shell command (pm install -r  "/data/local/tmp/SurfaceViewAnimation.apk"): closed
[2013-05-05 08:00:50 - ddms] ADB rejected shell command (rm /data/local/tmp/SurfaceViewAnimation.apk): closed
[2013-05-05 08:01:04 - ddms] ADB rejected shell command (getprop): closed
```

So, no 'retart adb in devices window', 'kill-server, restart-server', etc.  Eclipse recognizes my device, but cannot access device compatibility. Since getprop, rm, and pm are shell commands, attempting in terminal to access shell as root (su):

```
petemint14-Latitude-D810 pete-mint14 # adb shell
error: closed
```

Eclipse is opened as root.  All apps ran two weeks ago, no errors.
The only thing I can think of is an error in downloading a custom ROM to phone.  But re-flashing to stock ROM shows same errors, and it doesn't answer the question:  What is ADB trying to access (build.init ??), and why are terminal tools 'closed'?

Thank you for looking at the question again, I know it's tiresome, but the old responses of 'unplug/plugin', reset adb, restart computer, etc.. do not work.  I need to know what '... : closed' means...

Comment: You seem to have two different versions of ADB on your computer, which will cause no end of troubles.  Also you definitely do not want to be running Eclipse (or even ADB) as root.  And now that you have done so, you may have random build files left around owned by root, which a normal user cannot clean up or overwrite.  Anyway, without Eclipse or DDMS running, start up an adb shell and see if basic commands (try 'ls') work.  If not you have a broken android installation on the device.

Comment: @Chris Stratton Thank you!  Apparently I have a broken android installation on device.  I will re-install/upgrade Eclipse (without root) when Linux Mint15 comes out in a few days, and focus efforts on device.

Comment: If you found an answer please post it and accept it

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D I have not found an answer. Mint 15 is installed w/o root. My newest error that deals with rejected shell commands led me to my own previous question! I am currently investigating the use of both of xda-developer Chainfire's 'adbd Insecure' and 'SuperSU' apps for rooted phones...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem half hours ago，console views  **ADB is rejecting shell commands...**,but now this issue has been solved，just few steps

1. **Restart your phone and restar USB DEBUG!!**
2. **Reset adb**

and now you can run your application